# How download and install pyEDFlib library to Python 2.7 on Windows 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I use Python 2.7 through Anaconda. Me need pyEDFlib library. I tried to download the link, but I do not understand how to use GitHub in this case.

https://github.com/holgern/pyedflib

Comment: Downloaded from GitHub ( "<> Code", then "release", then have a file download, I chose the "zip").
From the unpacked archive ran "setup.py" - but the library is not established (checked in IDLE Python DUI command "import pyedflib" - ImportError: No module named pyedflib). How to install the downloaded module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either your command prompt or a bash shell you should be able to run,

```
pip install pyEDFlib
```

If you dont have the command `pip` just run,

```
python get-pip.py
```

I just did it on my computer and it worked. Hope this helps.

===================================================================
Possible problems and solutions:

```
- Proxy Error
```

I decided by sysadmin. After this run the command `pip install package_name`.

```
- Need setup numpy
```

Install numpy: `pip install numpy`.

```
- Use of the latest version pip
```

Upgrading pip command: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

```
- error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
```

Go to the link (http://aka.ms/vcpython27) and install Microsoft Visual C ++ 9.0. Re-Installation of the fact that the required Microsoft Visual C ++ 9.0

Comment: <Windows+R>
 pip install pyEDFlib - Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection
failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/pyedflib/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyEDFlib (from version
s: )
No matching distribution found for pyEDFlib

Comment: <Windows+R>  python get-pip.py - nothing :(

Comment: What happens when you just type `pip` into your command prompt? If it list a bunch of options, that means you do have `pip` so `python `get-pip.py` is not necessary. However the error you are receiving from `pip install pyEDFlib` looks like a proxy error, which means you have a proxy blocking your command prompt from accessing the internet . Are you behind a proxy? If so you need to add the flag `pip install pyEDFlib --proxy=<proxy address>`.

Comment: If you are not sure if you are behind a proxy server you need to go to: control panel-> Network and Internet->Internet Options->Connections->LAN Settings. If the box is checked under 'Proxy Server' then click 'Advanced' and you should be able to get the address of your proxy server.

Comment: When I enter `pip` (on the command line <Windows + R> -> `cmd` <Enter>) displays a list of commands for working with `pip`.

Comment: I tried to enter the following command: <br/>
`Pip install pyEDFlib --proxy [user: passwd @] proxy.server: port` in different versions (without the `[ ]` , `proxy =` , etc.) - in all cases, the same error.

Comment: I had a problem with the proxy server. Numpy set command: `pip install numpy`. Then run `pip install pyEDFlib`. loaded, I started to install, but gave an error and asked for update `pip`. Updated command: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Re-launched `pip install pyEDFlib` - error: `Running setup.py install for pyedflib ... error`